# PHP MongoDB find nested element

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

How can I do a select for all documents that have a parent.id that is equal to 3? I try doing this.parents.id == 3, but it doesn't seem to be working...

```
[parents] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => Folder 1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 3
        [title] => Folder 2
    )
)
```

Comment: and db.collectionName.find({'parents.id':3}) doesn't work either ?

Comment: and the php version : $collection->find(array('parents.id'=>3))

Comment: PHP version worked - thank you! I'm a mongo newbie, sorry :P

Comment: No pb, everyone is a beginner in something. Even gurus ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the PHP input is actually unclear. The PHP you provided could be one of the following JSON objects:

**Version 1:**

```
{ parents: 
  [ 
    { id: 1, title: "Folder 1" }, 
    { id: 3, title: "Folder 2" } 
  ] }
```

**Version 2:**

```
{ parents: 
  { 0: { id: 1, title: "Folder 1" }, 
    1: { id: 3, title: "Folder 2" } 
} }
```

If you do `find({'parents.id':3})` on **version 1**, this will work.

If you do `find({'parents.id':3})` on **version 2**, this will **not** work.

The difference is not clear in PHP, so use the command-line and double-check.

Comment: Thanks! As Frederik posted above, the correct code in PHP is this:
$collection->find(array('parents.id'=>3))

Comment: sorry it took so long, have been off the grid for a week :)